# Stop propagation of escape event from confirm() dialog

Tags: javascript

I have a dismissable form where I need to show confirmation on dismissing before closing it.

```js
const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
const textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  button.classList.add('hidden');
  textarea.classList.remove('hidden');
  textarea.focus();
});

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.key !== 'Escape') return;
  if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to close ?')) return;
  button.classList.remove('hidden');
  textarea.classList.add('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Edit</button>
<textarea class="hidden"></textarea>
```

The form (represented by the textarea) can be closed with the escape key.
But this escape key also controls the confirmation dialog, and it propagates to my handler.
So it closes the confirm dialog, then reopens it.

**Is there a way to prevent the propagation of the escape event from the confirm dialog to the textarea ?**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6215t4ny/2/)

Comment: `e.stopPropagation`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: use `keydown` instead https://jsfiddle.net/ht89eswk/

Comment: What platform(s) exhibit the described behavior? In Chrome 101.0.4951.54 on MacOS X 10.14.6, the snippet behaves as I'd expect:
* With focus on the textarea, hitting the ESC key opens the confirmation dialog once, and it stays open.
* With the confirmation dialog open, hitting ESC closes the confirmation dialog and returns to the textarea (still visible).
* Choosing the "Cancel" button in the confirmation dialog (with either mouse or keyboard) closes the dialog and returns to the textarea.
…

Comment: … * Choosing the "OK" button in the confirmation dialog (with either mouse or keyboard) closes the dialog and hides the textarea.

Comment: @outis for me with OPs fildde, Chrome 100.0.4896: click edit, textarea appears, press esc key, confirm appears, press esc key (close confirm), confirm closes then immediately reappears.    The confirm dialog is closing in keydown (verify by holding down esc, it closes immediately), but the textarea is confirming on keyup.

Comment: `confirm()` uses `keydown` for this very reason - so that the keydown/keyup (prev: keypress) on the focused element would not immediately close the dialog.   Use `keydown`.

Comment: @freedomn-m: what OS? I can only get that behavior if I hold down ESC long enough for it to start repeating.

Answer (score 1):

I added a flag that will store the fact you actually exited the dialog so that when the event gets fired again the next time it will use the flag to return from the handler:

```js
const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
const textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  button.classList.add('hidden');
  textarea.classList.remove('hidden');
  textarea.focus();
});

let dialogWasRefused = false;

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {  

  if(dialogWasRefused){
    dialogWasRefused = false;
    return;  
  } 
  
  if (e.key !== 'Escape') return;  
  if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to close (real message not from the fiddle platform) ?')) {
    dialogWasRefused = true;
    return;
  }
  button.classList.remove('hidden');
  textarea.classList.add('hidden');  
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Edit</button>
<textarea class="hidden"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks Diego that would do (my +1), but the `keydown` is actually simpler for me

Comment: I agree with that :)